# Using a factory class with generics

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class ThisClass<T>
{
    public T ThisInstance { get; set; }
    public int Infoflag { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a static factory method, for example:

```
public static ThisClass GetNewClass<T>(T instance) =>        
    new ThisClass<T>()
    {
        Infoflag = 3
    };
```

The issue that I'm having is that, because the instance class requires a type, I'm forced to declare the method like this:

```
public static ThisClass<T> GetNewClass(T instance) =>        
    new ThisClass<T>()
    {
        Infoflag = 3
    };
```

And then call it like this:

```
ThisClass<SomeClassType>.GetNewClass(instanceClass);
```

Which feels a little cumbersome; if I could have the type only on the method for the static method then I'd be able to use an inferred type, so:

```
ThisClass.GetNewClass(instanceClass);
```

Is this possible, or would I need to split the factory and instance classes up?

Comment: Is it a typo? I see `ThisClass` and `ThisClass<T>` which are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a static `ThisClass` helper class and put the static factory method there:

```
public static class ThisClass
{
    public static ThisClass<T> Create<T>(T instance) =>        
        new ThisClass<T>()
        {
            Infoflag = 3
        };
}
```

If you don't want consumers to create `ThisClass<T>` instances avoiding the factory method, then you could make it's constructor `internal` to make sure external assemblies will always have to call `Create<T>`. There are other more convoluted patterns you could also use to adress this issue, like making `ThisClass<T>` a nested type of `ThisClass` (no longer `static`) and exposing an interface; something along the following lines:

```
public interface IThisClass<T> { ... }

public class ThisClass
{
    private class InnerThisClass<T>: IThisClass<T> { ... }
    public static IThisClass<T> Create<T>(T instance) => ...
}
```

Without more data its hard to figure out what pattern suits you better.